# Change the date format in Velocity

Tags: velocity, date-format

I am a newbie in Velocity. I need to change a certain date format to another.

Eg: Change "Wed May 11 12:49:18 JST 2016" to "2016/05/11 12:49:18"

I found there is a DateTool to be included in VelocityContext in order to use $date.format("myFormat", myDate), but it doesn't work. May be I'm missing something.

I found a similar question, but I think its not answered properly.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156429/change-date-format-in-velocity

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following code in VelocityContext subclass:

```
context.put("date", new DateTool());
```

and used this date object in my .vm file like this:

```
Order Date : $ctx.date.format('yyyy/MM/dd H:m:s', ${ctx.order.date})
```

I referred below link:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Velocity/HowtouseDateinVelocity.htm